# JavaScript OOP call and onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, call, onbeforeunload

I have a small OOP plugin that i am writing and it's working besides the `onbeforeunload`

```
if(options.onbeforeunload && typeof options.onbeforeunload == 'function'){
               avacStatus.onbeforeunload = options.onbeforeunload;
               window.onbeforeunload=function(e){
                 e = e || window.event;
                 msg = "";
                 avacStatus.onbeforeunload.call(this,_userdata.username,msg,e);
                 return msg;
               };
            }
```

and in my code I have

```
avacStatus({
   onbeforeonload:function(name,msg,e){
     console.log(e); //works fine to log the event
     msg = name+ " you have an unsent status, if you leave you'll lose it";
   }
});
```

but when it comes to the `onbeforeunload` it only sends the default text and the actual msg in the function `msg="";` which isn't what I want. Am I doing this wrong? Why won't the object overwrite msg in the call method?

Comment: Because JavaScript is not pass-by-reference? You're not mutating that `msg` string, you're just creating a new value and doing nothing with it.

Comment: hmmm. Any suggestions then?

Comment: What is `avacStatus`? Once it seems to be the function to which you pass the `options` object, once it seems to be something else?

Comment: Suggestion: Just `return` the value from the `onbeforeonload` function!

Comment: No its the same thing. we have `avacStatus.init` which is `avacStatus` then there are prototypes of it `avacStatus.onbeforeunload` I'll try returning but it didn't work last time so

Comment: Just leave all that clutter away. Don't assign it to a property on `avacStatus`, just call it directly - like `options.onbeforeunload.call(…)`